# Get SUM from Iterator mediator esb wso2

Tags: javascript, iterator, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

I used Iterator and Script Mediator to calculate the sum of a student's grades.

I saw this problem i received each time the sum of 0 and noteis your say the totalnote does not take the variable note and increment
For example if I put the value of totalnote =16 it is the sum of 16 and note of each row

My goal is to add up these 4 notes

Here is my code

```
            <property name="totalnote" scope="default" type="INTEGER" value="0"/>
            <iterate expression="//etudiants/etudiant">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.etudiant.note)" name="note" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
                        <log level="custom">
                            <property expression="get-property('note')" name="msg"/>
                        </log>
                        <script language="js"><![CDATA[{var i = parseInt(mc.getProperty("note")) ;
var totalnote = parseInt(mc.getProperty("totalnote")) ;         
var totalnote = totalnote + i;
totalnote=totalnote.toString();
mc.setProperty("totalnote", totalnote);}]]></script>
                        <log level="custom">
                            <property expression="get-property('totalnote')" name="ms"/>
                        </log>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

and the result I received:

```
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,450]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} msg = 13
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,450]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} msg = 15
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,450]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} msg = 16
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,450]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} msg = 17
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,469]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} ms = 17
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,469]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} ms = 13
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,469]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} ms = 15
[2022-12-01 10:04:40,469]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:student} ms = 16
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add the Payload you are iterating and the result you expect after the Iteration?

Comment: This is the answer of get all where nom etudiant=rania{
    "etudiants": {
        "etudiant": [
            {
                "note": "17",
                "id": "2",
                "nom": "rania",
                "prenom": "ahmed",
                "age": "23"
            }  want to have with this list of the student Rania as shown here another Paylod contains the name and the sum of the note of the student Rania

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to get the sum of the `note` for all the students, you can simply use the following XPath expression,

```xml
<property expression="sum(//etudiants/etudiant/note[number(.) = number(.)])" name="totalnote" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Depeding on your payload you may need to update the expression. Here I have assumed a payload like below,

```json
{
  "etudiants": {
    "etudiant": [
      {
        "note": 17
      },
      {
        "note": 13
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You should use the `iterate mediator` if you want to make back-end calls from each iteration. Here for each iteration, a new message is created and you need to collect them by an `Aggregate mediator`.

If you just want to iterate over a payload you can use the `ForEach Mediator`. ForEach Mediator supports modifying the original payload as well.

For more info: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/iterate-mediator/